# Angular service call test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test that a button click triggers a service method call.
The component content (a bit cleaned) looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    try {
      //GET ALL ITEMS
      this.service.getAll().pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe((result) => {
        this.list = result;
      });
    }
    catch (ex) {
      this._utility.showNotification(ex, 2);
    }
  }

refresh() {
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

and the spec file looks like this:

```
it('REFRESH Button should call ngOnInit and getAll', () => {
    var spy = spyOn(component, "ngOnInit");
    var spyGet = spyOn(component.service, 'getAll').and.returnValue(of([]))
    let btnRefresh = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-info')).nativeElement
    btnRefresh.click()

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(spyGet).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  });
```

The current error what I get is the following:

> Expected spy getAll to have been called.

Comment: How can getAll have been called when you've mocked out the thing that was supposed to call it? Don't spyOn the thing you think you're testing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please explain in detail if you have down voted? yes, it's a mocked service that replaces the service method but I want to make sure that that method is called.

Comment: You want to make sure that getAll is called, yes. That it's done via ngOnInit (or refresh, for that matter) is an implementation detail. Again, don't spyOn the thing you think you're testing, the component.

Comment: I wouldn't spy on ngOnInit, the thing that's actually calling the thing you care about the button click calling. Also I wouldn't access the service via the component for test purposes, as that prevents making it private and is again testing implementation; inject a test double per e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing.

Comment: I believe you have to inject your service into the test. SpyOn gets a little wierd with injected 'things'

Comment: @SenAlexandru As mentioned by @jonrshape, Just remove the spy on  `ngOnInit`. You are good to go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed the spy on the component was the problem, and your final explanation eventually made things a bit clear, and I am thankful for that. On the other hand randomly down voting is really making these community less attractive since posting a question is by default reflecting a logic/programming mistake. best of luck in the future and thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to inject the service into your test first. Then, you spy on your injected services rather than what is in your component. Example:

```
it('should get stores', inject([StoresService], async (service: StoresService) => {
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getStores');
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: Don't you think injecting a service will create a new instance which is not the same as component's service instance? So spy may not be called.

Comment: No, it won't. I am using this in my unit tests and it works as expected. There are different ways to inject the service into the component. In the case above, yes, it would create a new service instance for that particular test. You can inject the service and use it globally throughout that components tests as well.

Comment: If it is creating a new instance for a particular test, then how would spy work? Because spy is on different instance of service and component is using different instance. The method that will be called is component's service instance method.

Comment: Read through some of the Jasmine/Angular documentation on how to test services in a component. You'll find the same solution.

Comment: Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#get-injected-services) recommends fetching the service instance from the `injector` which will return the component's service instance itself. Syntax: `service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(StoreService);`

Comment: As mentioned above, there are multiple ways to grab a service and inject it into your unit test. Point being, you have to get the injected reference. If you have any further updates, please create your own answer and your comments aren't helping here.

Comment: My only intention here was to tell that the injected service in the test spec is not always the same as component's instance. It can be same only if it is injected at test's root injector. So its always best to use `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(StoreService);`  Chill! have a good day:)

Answer (score 1):

removing the spy on the component did the trick

```
it('Refresh button should call getAll', () => {
   var spyGet = spyOn(MockApplicationLogService.prototype, 'getAll')
   let btnRefresh = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-info')).nativeElement
   btnRefresh.click()

   expect(spyGet).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```